# Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache

I am running ganache app locally in windows 10 and trying to connect with node app on localhost:8080 but getting below error[image: console]

Please help me!

Comment: I haven't worked much with Ganache, check if there is an option to enable CORS in that

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you are connecting to the correct ganache instance? What is your ganache version?